# How to set packet timeouts in Boost ASIO

Tags: boost-asio

I have an API server using Boost ASIO on Windows Server 2008R2 that works with one browser but not another.  The browser that doesn't work gets issued an RST from the server. I presume that the time waiting for an ACK is the culprit since the time waiting for ACK response is almost twice the response time (2.5 seconds) of the browser that works (before sending an RST).

In researching this issue is mainly done with Wireshark and examining the packet timing and RST/ACK replies.

The question is, is there a way to set the timeout in ASIO/Winsock to wait a little longer for the ACK packet and before issuing an RST?